# Highlight every word in vim that starts with an "&"

Tags: regex, vim

I somehow horribly fail in this task,

I try to solve it the following way

```
syntax keyword top "/&.*"
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick, the same goes for `"^&.*", /&.+, ...`

The syntax file is otherwise setup correctly (it shows other highlighting).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `match` and not `keyword`:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=&
syntax match top "\<&\w\+"
```

`iskeyword` allows vim to recognize `&` character as a part of keyword. That way, using `\<` we can match `&` at the beginning of word. So we match `&bar` in `foo &bar` and not in `foo&bar`.

**UPDATE**

@IngoKarkat's solution doesn't require modifying `iskeyword`:

```
syntax match top "\%(^\|\s\)\zs&\w\+"
```

Comment: I wouldn't modify `'iskeyword'` just for that and rather use `"\%(^\|\s\)\zs&\w\+"` (i.e. assert start of line or whitespace before the match).

Comment: @IngoKarkat I agree, touching `iskeyword` can have undesired side effects.